# I cannot enlarge an object ```div``` html with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practicing a little web design. Currently I am replicating the design of a timer that I saw somewhere on the internet. I am currently trying to create a circle (red object) between the digital clock screen and the 'Restart' button (Fig 1), but I cannot enlarge its size so that it occupies all the available space since, for some reason that I do not understand, it has a maximum space assigned (Fig 2).

Sketch of the expected design:

[image: Sketch of the expected design. Fig 1]

Current state with inspect item:

[image: Current state with inspect item. Fig 2]

How can i fix this?

```css
/* Import fonts */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
@font-face {
    font-family: 'digital-7';
    src: url('./source/digital-7.ttf');
}

:root {
    /* Colors */
    --white: #fff;
    --light-gray: #f0f0f3;

    --light-color: #ffffff;
    --shadow-color: #cccccf;

    /* Fonts */
    --roboto-font: Roboto;
    --font-style-bold: 700;
}

body {
    font-family: 'digital-7', sans-serif;
    background: var(--light-gray);
}

.page-head {
    background: var(--light-gray);

    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    top: 2%;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color);  

    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.tittle {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #31546a;

}

.options {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background: var(--light-gray);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;

    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;  
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color),  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color);
}

.options:hover { 
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 15px var(--light-color), 5px 5px 15px var(--shadow-color);
}

.options:active {
    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 10px var(--light-color), inset 3px 3px 10px var(--shadow-color);
    /*background: var(--light-gray);
    box-shadow: var(--light-gray);*/
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 8%;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color);

    padding: 15%;
}

.box-clock {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 70%;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -15px -15px 35px var(--light-color);
}

.digital-clock {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;

    border: #a8a8a8 solid 2px;

    background: linear-gradient(145deg, #cbd3c5, #afbca2);
    border-radius: 26px;
}

.clock-display {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333631;
}

.clock-field {
    margin-top: -21%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.clock-field div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.clock-field div p {
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.clock-field .numbers .placeholder {
    color: #adb7a4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 50;
}

.clock-field .numbers .type {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -118%;
}



.outer-circle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    background: rgb(255, 46, 46);
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -15px -15px 35px var(--light-color);
}

.restart {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;


    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;  
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color),  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color);
}

.restart:hover { 
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 15px var(--light-color), 5px 5px 15px var(--shadow-color);
}

.restart:active {
    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 10px var(--light-color), inset 3px 3px 10px var(--shadow-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<header class="page-head">
    <a class="tittle">Timer</a>
    <button class="options">Options</button>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-clock">
            <div class="digital-clock">
                <main class="clock-display">
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer-circle">Circle</div>

        <button class="restart">Restart</button>


    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

strong text

> Blockquote

use :https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_circles.asp

```css
/* Import fonts */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
@font-face {
    font-family: 'digital-7';
    src: url('./source/digital-7.ttf');
}

:root {
    /* Colors */
    --white: #fff;
    --light-gray: #f0f0f3;

    --light-color: #ffffff;
    --shadow-color: #cccccf;

    /* Fonts */
    --roboto-font: Roboto;
    --font-style-bold: 700;
}

body {
    font-family: 'digital-7', sans-serif;
    background: var(--light-gray);
}

.page-head {
    background: var(--light-gray);

    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    top: 2%;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color);  

    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.tittle {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #31546a;

}

.options {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background: var(--light-gray);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;

    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;  
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color),  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color);
}

.options:hover { 
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 15px var(--light-color), 5px 5px 15px var(--shadow-color);
}

.options:active {
    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 10px var(--light-color), inset 3px 3px 10px var(--shadow-color);
    /*background: var(--light-gray);
    box-shadow: var(--light-gray);*/
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 8%;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color);

    padding: 15%;
}

.box-clock {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 70%;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -15px -15px 35px var(--light-color);
}

.digital-clock {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;

    border: #a8a8a8 solid 2px;

    background: linear-gradient(145deg, #cbd3c5, #afbca2);
    border-radius: 26px;
}

.clock-display {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333631;
}

.clock-field {
    margin-top: -21%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.clock-field div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.clock-field div p {
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.clock-field .numbers .placeholder {
    color: #adb7a4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 50;
}

.clock-field .numbers .type {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -118%;
}



.dot {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow:  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color), -15px -15px 35px var(--light-color);
  }

.restart {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    bottom: 5%;


    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;  
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;

    background: var(--light-gray);
    box-shadow: -20px -20px 40px var(--light-color),  20px 20px 40px var(--shadow-color);
}

.restart:hover { 
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 15px var(--light-color), 5px 5px 15px var(--shadow-color);
}

.restart:active {
    box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 10px var(--light-color), inset 3px 3px 10px var(--shadow-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<header class="page-head">
    <a class="tittle">Timer</a>
    <button class="options">Options</button>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-clock">
            <div class="digital-clock">
                <main class="clock-display">
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="dot"></span>

        <button class="restart">Restart</button>


    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```